# pysvn: How to find out if local dir is under version control?

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

Using `pysvn` to check some SVN working copy properties.

What is the easy way of finding out if a local directory `c:\SVN\dir1` is under version control or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pysvn.Client.info`](http://pysvn.stage.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_info) will raise [`pysvn.ClientError`](http://pysvn.stage.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_clienterror) if you pass non working copy directory:

```
>>> import pysvn
>>> client = pysvn.Client()
>>> client.info('/tmp')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pysvn._pysvn_2_7.ClientError: '/tmp' is not a working copy
```

You can use that behavior. By catching the exception:

```
>>> try:
...     client.info('/tmp')
... except pysvn.ClientError:
...     print('not working copy')
... else:
...     print('working copy')
...
not working copy
```